# comparing decimal numbers in javascript

Tags: php

im having issues comparing km distance, it saying in the example above, im comparing distance between locations, these locations are in km.

```
9,441.4<1500
```

The output is telling me that 9 thousand is less than 1 thousand. In my case, should i only put or add in 1500 the dot and comma to be 1,500.0, or there is more than just that?

Comment: `,` ?????????? is that a `Number` or a `String` ????

Answer (score 5):

You should remove the comma. You don't use a thousands separator in JavaScript numbers.

So why didn't it fail with a syntax error? Because it's valid syntax: JavaScript has a comma *operator*. Your code was the number 9, followed by the comma operator, followed by the comparison `441.4 < 1500`. The comma operator is one of JavaScript's more...interesting...operators: It evaluates the left-hand operand (`9` in your example), throws away the resulting value, then evaluates its right-hand operand (`441.4<1500` in your example) and takes the resulting value as the value of the comma operator expression.

You wanted:

```
9441.4<1500
```

Comment: Hello, the problem is that i cant remove the comma from  9,441.4, is how it gets outputted from the api.

Comment: @Pedro: It's your only option, you'll have to either fix the API to output a valid JavaScript number, or handle the API's result as a string, remove the comma, and then evaluate that. If you run into trouble doing that, post a new, separate question with the full context so people can help you with that. But this is the answer to *this* question.

Comment: @Pedro API will return values in string. You will have to parse it manually. try `var n = parseFloat(apiNum.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''))`

Comment: Hello very sorry, but i just notice that im working this calculations on php, im sorry because im fixing something that is comming from my part, so in php applies the same situation?

Comment: @Pedro: I don't know much about PHP. The [operators page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php) doesn't mention a comma operator. I'm reasonably certain that `9,441.4` isn't a valid decimal number in PHP, though, so yes, in that sense removing the comma is the answer in PHP as well.

Answer (score 0):

As [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40817917/4989460) said, you need to remove the comma, and convert the string to a floating point number:

```
$api_input = "9,441.4";

$tmp = str_replace( ",", "", $api_input);

$distance = floatval($tmp);
```